# An unknown error has occurred 8004005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When i create the basic application in Visual studio for windows phone 2010 to link to a web browser and then type out this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string site = textBox1.Text;    

    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

When i build the application it shows as successful. However when i run debug and the emulator starts. When i press the button to navigate to a certain URL say google.com which is the text that I've mentioned in text box 1 , an error occurs

System.SystemException
An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80004005

Comment: how are you formatting the URL..? can you be more specific..?
This sounds like a System.Drawing error.. are you able to even debug this while it launches the emulator..?

Comment: You just got the mother of all funfun errors. Here's a link that might be helpful. It also might not be. (and yes it refers to classic asp, but most of the errors cross right over to .Net) http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-non-database-related-80004005-errors.html

Comment: This is a com exception -- something is going wrong with webBrowser1 or your call to it.

Comment: I am using  Visual studio for windows phone 2010. I have a text box which is the textbox1 that's mentioned in the code. I have typed on google.com in the text box, I also have a button that is the button 1 and on clicking the button, I'm asking it to go the URL mentioned in textbox 1. When i build the application, the build succeeds However, when I try to hit the button on the emulator, the visual studio 2010 express edition pops up I get the error with the code 8004005 unknown error

Comment: this sounds me to the library or dll's are corrupted

Answer (score 3):

The `Uri` only work with a complete URL start with scheme mentioned like `http://www.msn.com`
I think you should use `Uri.TryCreate()`

```
string site = textBox1.Text;
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(site, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it but the same error occured again. Anyway thanks for the reply :)

Comment: And if you do `http://google.com` instead of `google.com` in the text box, with your original code, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

A URI requires a scheme type (e.g. http://). Without that, you are likely ending up with what looks like a relative URI.

Use the [URI builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y868d5wh), which defaults to http when no scheme is specified:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(textBox1.Text);
webBrowser1.Navigate(builder.Uri);
```